# Can I detect when a user unlocks their phone with cordova/phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I'm using cordova to make an app where a timer is turned on once the user unlocks their android phone, is there any way I can use a plugin to detect when this happens?

I haven't found any way of fixing this issue

I'm hoping once this is finished I can start a timer when I've got this code, thank you so much for any help provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cordova-plugin-lock-info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-lock-info) can help with that. You might also want [cordova-plugin-background-mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) as well if you want the timer to continue even when the app is in the background. But be aware - your timer may or may not be accurate because your timer will not be running in the foreground at all times and may not be respected by the browser.